# Why is parameter in contravariant position?

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance, case-class

I'm trying to use a covariant type parameter inside a trait to construct a case-class like so:

```
trait MyTrait[+T] {
  private case class MyClass(c: T)
}
```

compiler says:

```
error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type T of value c
```

I then tried the following but it also didn't work:

```
trait MyTrait[+T] {
  private case class MyClass[U <: T](c: U)
}
```

the error this time is:

```
error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type >: Nothing <: T of type U
```

Could somebody explain why the T is in a covariant position here and suggest a solution for this problem? 
Thx!

Comment: Could you explain what it is you really want to do? Why do you want T covariant and not invariant?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a fundamental feature of object-oriented programming that doesn't get as much attention as it deserves.

Suppose you have a collection `C[+T]`.  What the `+T` means is that if `U <: T`, then `C[U] <: C[T]`.  Fair enough.  But what does it mean to be a subclass?  It means that *every method should work* that worked on the original class.  So, suppose you have a method `m(t: T)`.  This says you can take any `t` and do something with it.  But `C[U]` can only do things with `U`, which might not be all of `T`!  So you have immediately contradicted your claim that `C[U]` is a subclass of `C[T]`.  It's *not*.  There are things you can do with a `C[T]` that you can't do with a `C[U]`.

Now, how do you get around this?

One option is to make the class invariant (drop the `+`).  Another option is that if you take a method parameter, to allow *any superclass* as well: `m[S >: T](s: S)`.  Now if `T` changes to `U`, it's no big deal: a superclass of `T` is also a superclass of `U`, and the method will work.  (However, you then have to change your method to be able to handle such things.)

With a case class, it's even harder to get it right unless you make it invariant.  I recommend doing that, and pushing the generics and variance elsewhere.  But I'd need to see more details to be sure that this would work for your use case.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Your solution however does not work for me in this case. Dropping covariance and making the trait invariant would work but it's not what i want here. Allowing the method (or in my case the case-class) to take a supertype is also not satisfying. 
I'm curious to why things are harder to get right for case-classes. Note that the same code without the _case_ keyword works just fine.

Comment: @lapislazuli - Because case classes include a companion method that creates them (taking `T` as an argument), so you have to obey the method restrictions above.  If you don't include `case`, then the class doesn't imply a method in the interface that takes `T`s.

Comment: What's the reason that, in `class F[+A] { def f(x: A) = ??? }`, that `x` is in  `contravariant position`? Is it due to the `contravariance` of `T` in [Function[-T1, +R](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Function1.scala#L32)?

Answer (score 13):

Almost there. Here:

```
scala> trait MyTrait[+T] {
     |   private case class MyClass[U >: T](c: U)
     | }
defined trait MyTrait
```

Which means `MyClass[Any]` is valid for all `T`. That is at the root of why one cannot use `T` in that position, but demonstrating it requires more code than I'm in the mood for at the moment. :-)