# Why method defined like "cons[B >: A](v: B)" accepts argument of type which is not supertype of A?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance, contravariance, generic-method

I am studying variance in scala right now, and I think I have a good understanding of contravariance. For example given `trait List[-A]`, I know that `List[Int]` is a supertype of `List[AnyVal]`.

But say that I have the following trait:

```
trait List[+A] {
  def cons(hd: A): List[A]
}
```

**Why is `cons` parameter type wrong?**

Why it is necessary to have `def cons[B >: A](v: B): List[B]` ?

For example:

```
val animal_list: List[Animal] = List(tiger, dog)
```

if we call:

```
animal_list.cons(tiger)
```

**since `Tiger <: Animal`, doesn't `cons` ran into problem?** Since `B` is `Tiger` and `A` is `Animal` and `B >: A` is not true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why is `cons`'s parameter type wrong?

```
trait List[+A] {
  def cons(hd: A): List[A]
}
```

Compiler give you error:
`covariant type A occurs in contravariant position in type A of value hd`
**because method parameters count as contravariant positions, but `A` is covariant.**

Let's imagine that this method declaration would compile. Then we could do:

```
class ListImpl[A] extends List[A] {
  override def cons(hd: A): List[A] = ???
}

val strings: List[String] = new ListImpl[String]
val values: List[Any] = strings // OK, since List[String] <: List[Any] (in List[A], A is covariant)
values.cons(13) // OK(??), since values's static type is List[Any], so argument of cons should be Any, and 13 conforms to type Any
```

Is the last line above really OK? We are calling `cons` on `values`. `values` is the same as `strings`, and `strings` is object of type `ListImpl[String]`. So `cons` invocation in the last line is expecting `String` argument, but we are passing `Int`, because `values`'s static type is `List[Any]` and `Int` conforms to `Any`. Something is definitely wrong here - which line is to blame? The answer is: `cons` method declaration. To fix this issue, we have to remove covariant type parameter `A` from contravariant position (in `cons` declaration). Alternatively we can make `A` non-covariant.

See also these questions: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619121/why-is-parameter-in-contravariant-position), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584830/covariant-type-t-occurs-in-contravariant-position).

## ... doesn't `cons` ran into problem?

```
trait List[+A] {
  def cons[B >: A](v: B): List[B]
}

val animal_list: List[Animal] = List(tiger, dog)  // We are assuming that List.apply and concrete implementation of List is somewhere defined.
```

**No, `animal_list.cons(tiger)` invocation is type-correct.**

I assume that `Animal` is common supertype of `Dog` and `Tiger`, and that `dog` and `tiger` are instances of `Dog` and `Tiger` respectively.

In `animal_list.cons(tiger)` invocation, both `A` and `B` type parameters are instantiated to `Animal`, so `cons` method takes form of:

```
def cons[Animal >: Animal](v: Animal): List[Animal]
```

`Animal >: Animal` constraint is satisfied because:

> Supertype and subtype relationships are reflexive, which means a type
>   is both a supertype and a subtype of itself. [[source](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/type-parameterization.html#footnote19-1)]

The argument to `cons` is `Tiger` which conforms to type `Animal`, so the method invocation is type-correct.

Notice that if you force `B` to be instantiated to `Tiger`, like `animal_list.cons[Tiger](tiger)`, then this invocation won't be type-correct, and you'll get compiler error.

See similar example [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implementing-lists.html#lst:cons-method-def).

Comment: Oh I see, so the reason that `Tiger` was able to be passed to `cons` despite `Tiger <: Animal` is because `Tiger` get typecast to `Animal` first?

Comment: @testing - With declaration `def cons[B >: A](v: B): List[B]` you can pass object of any type to `cons` - type argument `B` will always be instantiated to the most precise common supertype of `A` and the type of `cons`'s argument. Passing object to method which expects supertype argument is normal OO thing - e. g. you can always pass `Tiger` when `Animal` is expected.

Comment: What if I have `val tiger_list: List[Tiger] = List(tiger)` this would imply `tiger_list.con(animal)` is valid? shouldn't we have something like `def cons[B >: A][C <: A](v: B): List[C]`

Comment: @testing - When you call `List(tiger).cons(animal)` then `B` will be instantiated to the most precise common supertype of `Tiger` and `Animal`, which is `Animal`. When you call `List(tiger).cons(7)` then `B` will be instantiated to `Any`, because it is the most precise common supertype of `Tiger` and `Int`. If you are still confused, then run this code in REPL, and see what `cons` returns for different types of arguments.