# Scala higher kinded type variance

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I am dipping my toes in higher kinded types, exploring a very basic Scala example:

```
trait Mappable[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

object Mappable {
  implicit object MappableOption extends Mappable[Option] {
    def map[A, B](fa: Option[A])(f: A => B): Option[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
  implicit object MappableSeq extends Mappable[Seq] {
    def map[A, B](fa: Seq[A])(f: A => B): Seq[B] = fa.map(f)
  }
}

def bananaTuple[F[_], T](f: F[T])(implicit F: Mappable[F]): F[(String, T)] =
  F.map(f)(("banana", _))
```

This works:

```
bananaTuple(Option(42)) // Some((banana,42))
bananaTuple(Seq(42))    // List((banana,42))
```

But this does not compile:

```
bananaTuple(Some(42))
bananaTuple(List(42))
```

The compile errors I get:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter F: ch.netzwerg.hkt.HigherKindedTypes.Mappable[Some] bananaTuple(Some(42))

not enough arguments for method bananaTuple: (implicit F: ch.netzwerg.hkt.HigherKindedTypes.Mappable[Some])Some[(String, Int)]. Unspecified value parameter F. bananaTuple(Some(42))
```

How can I bring variance into the game?

Comment: The F argument for Mappable is invariant so you won't be able to fix this with variance annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We *can* make this work with a little more parameteric polymorphism:

```
object MappableExample {
  trait Mappable[F[_]] {
    type Res[_]
    def map[A, B](f: A => B)(c: F[A]): Res[B]
  }

  implicit def seqMappable[C[X] <: Seq[X]] = new Mappable[C] {
    type Res[X] = Seq[X]
    override def map[A, B](f:A => B)(c: C[A]): Seq[B] = c.map(f)
  }

  implicit def optionMappable[C[X] <: Option[X]]: Mappable[C] = new Mappable[C] {
    type Res[X] = Option[X]
    override def map[A, B](f: A => B)(c: C[A]): Option[B] = c.map(f)
  }

  def map[A, B, C[_]](xs: C[A])(f: A => B)(implicit mappable: Mappable[C]): mappable.Res[B] = {
    mappable.map(f)(xs)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(map(List(1,2,3))(("banana", _)))
    println(map(Some(1))(("banana", _)))
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
List((banana,1), (banana,2), (banana,3))
Some((banana,1))
```

The compiler now infers `Some` as `Mappable[Some]#Res[Int]` and `Mappable[List]#Res[Int]` which is quite ugly. One would expect the compiler to actually be able to infer the right type without needing for any co/contravariance on the `Mappable` trait, which we can't do since we're using it in an invariant position.

Comment: Nice idea. Btw typo alert - you're using names Res and Out interchangeably.

Comment: @slouc Whoops. Fixed. :)

Comment: It only infers ugly types because you specified the return type as `Mappable[C]`, instead of `Mappable[C] { type Res[X] = Option[X] }`. Which you can clean up a bit with the [Aux pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38541271/what-does-the-aux-pattern-accomplish-in-scala).

Comment: @Jasper-M How would you use the Aux pattern here? Can't seem to fit it to the solution (haven't used it before).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I meant just for shortening the return types, if you have a lot of `Mappable` instances. So that you can write `Mappable.Aux[C,Option]` instead of `Mappable[C] { type Res[X] = Option[X] }`. Although it could also come in handy when you want to combine multiple typeclasses: `def foo[C[_],Res[_],A,B](c: C[A])(f: A => B)(implicit m: Mappable.Aux[C,Res], s: Summable[Res, B]): B = s.sum(m.map(c)(f))`. But that's getting a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Jasper-M Oh, I see what you mean know. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Subtype polymorphism allows us to pass values of a certain type or any of its subtypes to a method. If a method takes a value of type Fruit, we can also pass an Apple inside (an apple is a fruit after all). So if you want to be able to pass a Mappable.MappableOption to your bananaTuple method, you have to make that MappableOption a subtype of MappableSome (since the type of your first parameter of bananaTuple dictates the implicit one). This means that you want your Mappable contravariant (if `Some <: Option`, then `Mappable[Some] >: Mappable[Option]`).

But you cannot have `Mappable[F[_]]` contravariant in F because F appears in covariant position of `map` (as a function parameter). Note that F also appears in contravariant position of `map` (as a return value).

If you manage to make `Mappable[F[_]]` contravariant in F, it should work, but I'm not sure if making it contravariant makes sense. That is, if you want a subtype relationship such as e.g. `Apple <: Fruit` to result in `Mappable[Apple] >: Mappable[Fruit]` (this would not compile since Apple and Fruit are not type constructors, but I'm just using simple types to make a point here).

Making a type contravariant in its type and solving the problem of contravariant type appearing in covariant position is a common problem and perhaps it's better if you search for it elsewhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9619950/5599298) is one example). I still think that it's better to provide an implicit object for every type you want to use, that is, to provide separate implicit objects for e.g. `Seq` and `List`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, your code works perfectly. However, if I try to port your suggestion to my example (where HKT are involved), it still doesn't work: `bananaTuple(Some(42))(Mappable.MappableOption)` does not compile _"[...] trait Mappable is invariant in type F. You may wish to define F as -F instead."_ Would you mind explaining it with exactly the types I showed in the example?

Comment: OK edited my question, since my original answer is a bit off-topic (you don't have classes such as Foo and Foo2, but just one Mappable).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Somehow, mutability is not only bad in code, but also when it comes to SO answers. Now that you have edited your answer, my comment above reads like complete nonsense – nevermind ;-)

Comment: Haha, sorry about that :D I just moved the comments to the answer.